# How to Deploy a Cake PHP App

Tags: php, cakephp

I wonder if someone can help me. I've been handed in a Cake PHP app that I need to 1) add minor changes 2) deploy. I've never really worked with Cake before and was wondering whether do I need to anything in order for it to work?

For instance, With a Node app, you need to install modules `npm install`. With a Rails app you'll likely need to install the gems `bundle install`.

Is there something similar with Cake? I've set the localhost server, but when I try to access the url I get all sort of errors. Some I've fixed (missing environment settings which I just override the Redis host and port). The latest one is:

```
{
  "exception":{
    "class":"MissingControllerException",
    "code":404,
    "message":"Controller class Controller could not be found.",
    "file":"\/Library\/WebServer\/Documents\/php\/oompbe\/vendors\/cakephp\/lib\/Cake\/Routing\/Dispatcher.php",
    "line":154,
    "trace":[
      "#0 \.../app\/webroot\/index.php(109): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))",
      "#1 {main}"
    ]
  }
}
```

PS: What's up with all the crazy `\/\/`?
PPS: Can I find out the version Cake I'm running?

Comment: CakePHP is just PHP, if your app is using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) - that's what to read up on, otherwise there is no deploy step apart from moving files. The error message suggests missing/malconfigured routes. regarding slashes that's how [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) works, and why the option JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES exists. The path in the error indicates it's 2.x - look for the file lib/Cake/VERSION.txt, or (if your app works) just [launch the cli](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#the-cakephp-console) `Console/cake`.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! Would you like to add an answer so I can accept it? And for what I've been reading it seems to I do need to run `composer install`

Comment: Besides the already asked, would you define "deployement" a little more precise? "Deployment" is a very broad term. What *exactly* do you want to do? Deploying a cake app on a live system? Fully automated?

Comment: What were you reading? CakePHP 2 itself doesn't use composer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP is just php. As most properly done php apps these days it comes with [composer](http://composer.org/). I recommend you to read at least the basics of it's manual. Composer is an awesome tool.

```
git clone <repo>
cd <reponame>
composer install
```

If you start a *new* Cake application [the official documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#installing-cakephp) tells you how to this as well:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app [app_name]
```

If you want to automate things further [composer provides you callback scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#event-names). They'll allow you to automate tasks, basically trigger commands, after different actions. This is pretty useful to build assets after a `composer update` for example. I recommend you to not put lots of commands into that section but instead have dedicated script files you trigger by the callbacks.

> Can I find out the version Cake I'm running?

If installed via composer it is usually in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/version.txt`. Check the content of that file.